# Prevent iPhone "Trust this computer" on work PC

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, usb, charge

I would like to charge my iPhone using a USB plug on my Windows PC at work.
However, any time I begin charging with the phone unlocked, it prompts me:

> **Trust This Computer**
>   Your settings and data will be accessible from this computer when connected.
>   <kbd>Trust</kbd> <kbd>Don't Trust</kbd>

In my case, I never want to trust this PC, and I never want to accidentally click "Trust".
Is there a way to keep the phone from prompting me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy "charge only" cables.  For examples open Amazon and type "usb charge only cable" in search.

Electrically a "charge only" just connects the power pins, and not the serial date pins between the computer and device.

Comment: Great idea. There are also charge-only adapters available that simply drop the two data pins. A quick search on Amazon found them for only a few dollars.

Comment: Perfect.​​​​​​​

Comment: I suppose 15 hours was long enough to wait for any other contenders.  :)

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: @robert yea links like that do expire... Replaced with text...